# Can I add python to an eas build worker instance?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I've a build that works on my m1 mac and succeeds on eas build but some packages are missing when I try to access the app on a simulator.  I'm getting errors in the "Install custom tools" build step.

I suspect it has something to due with python not being installed on the eas build worker instance.  Is there any way I can install python or select a worker instance which has it installed?

I've already tried adding a pre-install hook and installing python there but this build step executes after "install custom tools".

I've also consulted the [eas](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/eas-json/) [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/) but can't seem to find a way to modify the worker instance image to install additional custom tools (in this case Python).

Relevant part of "Install Custom Tools" log:

```
Now using node v14.21.3 (npm v6.14.18)

/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/sharp -> /Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/sharp-cli/bin/cli.js

> sharp@0.25.4 install /Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/sharp-cli/node_modules/sharp

> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info

sharp Detected globally-installed libvips v8.14.2

info

sharp Building from source via node-gyp

CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o

LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a

env: python: No such file or directory

...

Failed to install sharp-cli@1.15.0 for Node.js v14.21.3

If your version of Node.js does not support 1.15.0 version of sharp-cli

 - build will fallback to slower (JS only) implementation.

 - you can install different version in "eas-build-pre-install" hook (https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/how-tos/#eas-build-specific-npm-hooks)
```